# eBay Orders Buyer Paid

Tags: ebay-api

I have an order where the buyer paid the shipping to eBay, however, it's not on the order. It's international shipping and the buyer paid it.

[image]

You will see the shipping service cost is $26.15, however, the shipping and handling is $0 in the image. Am I reading the wrong field for shipping?

Request

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"></RequesterCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
      <MessageID>9682099a-9dbd-45b0-a2bb-c9caa4bb42ea</MessageID>
      <Version>779</Version>
      <OrderIDArray>
        <OrderID>161926872948-1351674703006</OrderID>
      </OrderIDArray>
    </GetOrdersRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2016-01-07T19:47:34.216Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Success</Ack>
   <CorrelationID>c310b4b7-b81b-4c9b-ba91-0a434feabf06</CorrelationID>
   <Version>949</Version>
   <Build>E949_CORE_APIXO_17770993_R1</Build>
   <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>1</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
   </PaginationResult>
   <HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
   <OrderArray>
    <Order>
     <OrderID>161926872948-1351674703006</OrderID>
     <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
     <AdjustmentAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</AdjustmentAmount>
     <AmountPaid currencyID="USD">56.1</AmountPaid>
     <AmountSaved currencyID="USD">0.0</AmountSaved>
     <CheckoutStatus>
      <eBayPaymentStatus>NoPaymentFailure</eBayPaymentStatus>
      <LastModifiedTime>2016-01-07T19:28:25.000Z</LastModifiedTime>
      <PaymentMethod>PayPal</PaymentMethod>
      <Status>Complete</Status>
      <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>false</IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
     </CheckoutStatus>
     <ShippingDetails>
      <SalesTax>
       <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
       <SalesTaxState></SalesTaxState>
       <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
       <SalesTaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</SalesTaxAmount>
      </SalesTax>
      <ShippingServiceOptions>
       <ShippingService>ShippingMethodExpress</ShippingService>
       <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
       <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
       <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
       <ShippingTimeMax>4</ShippingTimeMax>
      </ShippingServiceOptions>
      <InternationalShippingServiceOption>
       <ShippingService>InternationalPriorityShipping</ShippingService>
       <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
       </InternationalShippingServiceOption>
      <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>74748</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
      <TaxTable>
       <TaxJurisdiction>
        <SalesTaxPercent>8.25</SalesTaxPercent>
        <ShippingIncludedInTax>true</ShippingIncludedInTax>
       </TaxJurisdiction>
      </TaxTable>
      <GetItFast>false</GetItFast>
     </ShippingDetails>
     <CreatedTime>2016-01-04T18:42:01.000Z</CreatedTime>
     <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
     <SellerEmail>Invalid Request</SellerEmail>
     <ShippingAddress>
      <Name></Name>
      <Street1></Street1>
      <Street2></Street2>
      <CityName></CityName>
      <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
      <Country>IL</Country>
      <CountryName></CountryName>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <PostalCode>55900</PostalCode>
      <ExternalAddressID></ExternalAddressID>
     </ShippingAddress>
     <ShippingServiceSelected>
      <ShippingService>InternationalPriorityShipping</ShippingService>
      <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">26.15</ShippingServiceCost>
     </ShippingServiceSelected>
     <Subtotal currencyID="USD">29.95</Subtotal>
     <Total currencyID="USD">56.1</Total>
     <ExternalTransaction>
      <ExternalTransactionID>XX</ExternalTransactionID>
      <ExternalTransactionTime>2016-01-04T18:42:00.000Z</ExternalTransactionTime>
      <FeeOrCreditAmount currencyID="USD">1.26</FeeOrCreditAmount>
      <PaymentOrRefundAmount currencyID="USD">56.1</PaymentOrRefundAmount>
     </ExternalTransaction>
     <TransactionArray>
      <Transaction>
       <Buyer>
        <Email>Invalid Request</Email>
        <UserFirstName></UserFirstName>
        <UserLastName></UserLastName>
       </Buyer>
       <ShippingDetails>
        <CalculatedShippingRate>
         <OriginatingPostalCode>63126</OriginatingPostalCode>
         <PackageDepth measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">7</PackageDepth>
         <PackageLength measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">11</PackageLength>
         <PackageWidth measurementSystem="English" unit="inches">1</PackageWidth>
         <PackagingHandlingCosts currencyID="USD">0.0</PackagingHandlingCosts>
         <ShippingIrregular>false</ShippingIrregular>
         <ShippingPackage>PackageThickEnvelope</ShippingPackage>
         <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
         <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">3</WeightMinor>
        </CalculatedShippingRate>
        <SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>74748</SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber>
       </ShippingDetails>
       <CreatedDate>2016-01-04T18:42:01.000Z</CreatedDate>
       <Item>
        <ApplicationData>XX</ApplicationData>
        <ItemID>XX</ItemID>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <Title>Becca Shimmering Skin Perfector - Opal (1.7oz/50ml)....</Title>
        <SKU>BECSHIOPA</SKU>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <ConditionDisplayName>New</ConditionDisplayName>
       </Item>
       <QuantityPurchased>1</QuantityPurchased>
       <Status>
        <PaymentHoldStatus>None</PaymentHoldStatus>
       </Status>
       <TransactionID>1351674703006</TransactionID>
       <TransactionPrice currencyID="USD">29.95</TransactionPrice>
       <TransactionSiteID>US</TransactionSiteID>
       <Platform>eBay</Platform>
       <Taxes>
        <TotalTaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TotalTaxAmount>
        <TaxDetails>
         <Imposition>SalesTax</Imposition>
         <TaxDescription>SalesTax</TaxDescription>
         <TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxAmount>
         <TaxOnSubtotalAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnSubtotalAmount>
         <TaxOnShippingAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnShippingAmount>
         <TaxOnHandlingAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxOnHandlingAmount>
        </TaxDetails>
        <TaxDetails>
         <Imposition>WasteRecyclingFee</Imposition>
         <TaxDescription>ElectronicWasteRecyclingFee</TaxDescription>
         <TaxAmount currencyID="USD">0.0</TaxAmount>
        </TaxDetails>
       </Taxes>
       <ActualShippingCost currencyID="USD">26.15</ActualShippingCost>
       <ActualHandlingCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ActualHandlingCost>
       <OrderLineItemID>161926872948-1351674703006</OrderLineItemID>
      </Transaction>
     </TransactionArray>
     <PaidTime>2016-01-04T18:42:01.000Z</PaidTime>
     <ShippedTime>2016-01-05T18:04:57.000Z</ShippedTime>
     <IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>false</IntegratedMerchantCreditCardEnabled>
     <EIASToken>nY+sHZ2PrBmdj6wVnY+sEZ2PrA2dj6AEloWlDpKLpA6dj6x9nY+seQ==</EIASToken>
     <PaymentHoldStatus>None</PaymentHoldStatus>
     <MonetaryDetails>
      <Payments>
       <Payment>
        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
        <Payer type="eBayUser">XX</Payer>
        <Payee type="eBayPartner">XX</Payee>
        <PaymentTime>2016-01-04T18:42:00.000Z</PaymentTime>
        <PaymentAmount currencyID="USD">26.15</PaymentAmount>
       </Payment>
       <Payment>
        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
        <Payer type="eBayUser">XX</Payer>
        <Payee type="eBayUser">XX</Payee>
        <PaymentTime>2016-01-04T18:42:00.000Z</PaymentTime>
        <PaymentAmount currencyID="USD">29.95</PaymentAmount>
        <ReferenceID type="ExternalTransactionID">XX</ReferenceID>
        <FeeOrCreditAmount currencyID="USD">1.26</FeeOrCreditAmount>
       </Payment>
      </Payments>
     </MonetaryDetails>
    </Order>
   </OrderArray>
   <OrdersPerPage>100</OrdersPerPage>
   <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
   <ReturnedOrderCountActual>1</ReturnedOrderCountActual>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You would be better off contacting eBay support, you may be using the ebay api but saying it is appropriate for stackoverflow is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: It is because they used Global Shipping, you don't collect money from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the order is because is using Global Shipping it will show 0.00.

Please check the API documentation on the [getordersapi](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html#Response.OrderArray.Order.IsMultiLegShipping) or [getmyebayselling](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getmyebayselling.html#Response.SoldList.OrderTransactionArray.OrderTransaction.Transaction.IsMultiLegShipping) api.

Take a look at the tag

```
<IsMultiLegShipping> boolean </IsMultiLegShipping>
```

You can exclude these pass through payments if it is true.

In order to see `<IsMultiLegShipping>` you will need to pass this with your request:

```
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
```

[DetailLevel: ReturnAll. Also returned if DetailLevel is not provided on input.](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html#Request.DetailLevel)

Comment: Thanks, I posted on the eBay forum too. I cannot find the multileg shipping element, though.

Comment: You need to provide detail level with your request, I updated the answer.

Comment: Please see my latest post update. I am sending the detail level, but I receive no IsMultiLeg shipping.

Comment: You probably need to change the version to one that will give you that tag. change it to 949 in your request (<Version>779</Version>)